# How to organise a Go project with vendorised dependencies?

Tags: git, go

I'm working on a Go project that isn't a package but a service. It depends on `mgo`, among other things. Because this service is legally supposed to be securely versioned and highly available we've made the decision to vendorize the `mgo` dependency within the project. Due to the legal requirement we can't just rely on pulling whatever version is on `origin/master` for the dependency.

Obviously this breaks our `GOPATH` for all standard commands as it's no longer living under `GOPATH` but in a `vendor` directory within the Git repository:

```
~/src/link_tracker/
  main.go
  main_test.go
  vendor/
    src/
      labix.org/
        etc...
```

We're currently working around this using a fairly ugly Bash script that mangle lots of environment variables and does some symlinking, but it'd be nice if we could consolidate all this under a Makefile or similar.

What's the best/right way to organise this without losing our specifically versioned dependency of `mgo`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use https://github.com/kr/godep to solve this problem now is very stable, the thing to have on account is that your code should be on a repository(git, svn, mercurial , among others).

Answer (score 0):

The two tools I've been playing with (for similar goals) are:

- https://github.com/mattn/gom
- https://github.com/VividCortex/johnny-deps

You should probably see if you can use one of them instead of rolling your own. In the particular case of the labix.org stuff, johnny-deps appears to require things to be git-hosted.

Comment: Wanted to avoid something like that - it's yet another dependency on any environments that need to build things.